# Jquery, event.stopPropagation for widget-controlled elements

Tags: jquery

I've widget, which works like selector (but not a real one). I'm using event.stopPropagation() to control drop-down list with elements, but problem is, when there is more than one element on page - I can open multiple drop-down lists at the same time.

Is there any possible ways to fix that?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9gas2h/

Controls for click is on 76-88 row:

```
this.clicktarget.on('click', function (event) {
            if (source.options.allfields) {
                if (!$(event.target).hasClass('deadfield')) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    source._open($(event.target));
                    source._runcheck();
                }
            } else {
                event.stopPropagation();
                source._open($(event.target));
                source._runcheck();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide all drop-down lists before opening clicked one:

```
this.clicktarget.on('click', function (event) {
    $(".multiple-selector-table").hide();
    ... other you code
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9gas2h/2/).

Updated. Another option:

You can use the following code to trigger `_close` for each drop-down element:

```
this.clicktarget.on('click', function (event) {
    $(window).click();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9gas2h/2/).

Comment: Not the best way, widget logic must not follow outside of controlled element.

Comment: @Dazvolt well, you can notify all elements that they should be closed using updated code... In general, you can only either notify all elements, or keep list of all elements and call `_close` for each one.